# How to get multiple lines from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch from mysql table multiple lines data, for example:

```
1 car

2 shop

3 dress
```

But for now it's only fetch the first line.

My code so far:

```
    case "2":
            ResultSet rsl2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT payments FROM payment;" );
            while(rsl2.next()) {
                String sqlRes = rsl2.getString("payments"); 
                System.out.println(sqlRes);
                if (sqlRes != null) {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    return sqlRes;
                }

            }
```

Comment: You are executing `return sqlRes;` for first non-null `sqlRes`. Why? Returning value from method moves control flow out of this method which also stops loops in it.

Comment: You are `return`ing after finding the first value, what did you expect? Put `return` after the `while` loop and you'll get all values printed.

Comment: When i write the return after the while loop I get an error "sqlRes cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Most likely you want to add `sqlRes` to some kind of `Collection`, like an `ArrayList` (which you create before the loop) and return that after it.

Comment: Put this in a loop, like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Answer (score 0):

You may either append all your data to the `sqlRes` variable

```
sqlRes += rsl2.getString("payments");
```

and change your if statement to

```
if (sqlRes == null)
    return sqlRes;
```

or place your return statement after the while loop. Either way, you should append the data in the `sqlRes` variable if you finally want the returned value to hold all the values in your DB.